# Multiple results in people picker of hosted name site collection with ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-2013, adfs

I am having a problem when setting up ADFS in a web application which have hosted name site collections. Although I put ADFS authentication in a different zone, but in my hosted site name collections, I still can search for ADFS accounts. Please refer to the detailed info below:

My situation is:

- I have a web application which have 2 hosted name site collections. It is using NTML authentication in Default Zone.
- In order to use ADFS, I extended the web application to Internet Zone
- However, during the extending web application, I think the SercurityTokenServiceApplication got some problems. I had to restart application pool of the SecurityTokenServiceApplication. After that I continued to configure ADFS in sharepoint.

Then my problem is:

- The login via ADFS works perfectly. However, I have got a problem with the people picker of the hosted name site collections. When I opened the people picker to check permission, I tried to enter an account and the people picker showed both results from ActiveDirectory and ADFS. This problem now is in production farm, but it did not happen in my staging farm. I think it is because the SecurityTokenServiceApplication was not down at the time I set up in the stating environment.
- I tried to reproduce the problem in my testing environment by stopping the SecurityTokenServiceApplication during extending web application step, then I got the same problem in the production.
- However, the path-based site collections in the web application do not have this problem. Every hosted name site collection have issue.
- I even tried to delete the web application and recreate again but the problem still exists.

From my understanding, if I set up that way, only site collections from Internet zone can retrieve users from ADFS. However, I do not know how to resolve the above problem. If there is any one experienced the same problem, please kindly advise.

Thanks a lot.